# Advice for sharing a guest vm's files with the host

Tags: ubuntu, freebsd, kvm-switch, nfs

I've got a RAIDZ array on a FreeBSD guest.  My host is Ubuntu 10.04 running KVM.  I'd like to mount the array on the host OS somehow and access the files as efficiently as possible.

Any advice?  Should I be using NFS?  If so, UDP or TCP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the virtualization uses one of the standard disk image formats - or even better, if you're using real disks for your guest OS, you can either use the images or physical disks direct from Linux using the [fuse version of ZFS](http://zfs-fuse.net/).  This will be much more efficient than doing anything through networking - even virtual networking.

***NOTE:*** *You don't want to have the VM running when you do this*

Answer (score 0):

One option is to share one of the host's folders via the VM GUI, then map a drive inside the guest to the host's share. I have no idea how the performance would compare to NFS.

Answer (score 0):

What VM software are you using?  VirtualBox provides "host folders" access, but this is only one-way (so the guest can access the host's folders).

How do you have the network configured?  If the guest is running on a private network with the host, use NFS with TCP (UDP is BAD here -- UDP is a lossy protocol that doesn't care if it drops packets, and you don't want that when transferring files).  You might also want to look into other options like (S)FTP or SMB to transfer files.

Comment: I'm using KVM for virtualization.  Also, can you please comment on whether the lossy nature of UDP matters in the case of two OSes on the same machine.  Losses are less likely this way, right?  And using UDP doesn't mean that you could get a corrupted file, does it?